# Javascript || operator still returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add values from a database. If the ajax call returns no data, the values are null and i get a NaN. So, I am using the || operator but I am still getting NaN. What am I doing wrong?

```
var total = (parseFloat(value[8])+parseFloat(value[9])+parseFloat(value[10])+parseFloat(value[11])).toFixed(1)  || 0;
```

Comment: Try something like `!isNaN(yourNumber) ? yourNumber : 0`

Comment: NaN.toFixed(0) returns "NaN" which evaluates to true with ||

Comment: Mind your brackets. `(NaN).toFixed(1) || 0` == `NaN` while `(NaN || 0).toFixed(1)` = `0.0`.

Comment: @Matthijs That worked! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logic needs to be inversed. You are evaluating the result of all the values at the end, when you should be evaluating each separate value. You can write a wrapper function to parse each of the values.

```js
// Safely parse a float to the value or zero.
function parseValue(value) {
  return parseFloat(value) || 0;
}

var value = []; // Values are intentionally empty.

var total = (
    parseValue(value[8]) +
    parseValue(value[9]) +
    parseValue(value[10]) +
    parseValue(value[11])
).toFixed(1);

document.body.innerHTML = total; // Prints 0.0
```

Or you could move the `|| 0` inside the summation of the values.

```js
var value = []; // Values are intentionally empty.

var total = (
    parseFloat(value[8]) +
    parseFloat(value[9]) +
    parseFloat(value[10]) +
    parseFloat(value[11]) ||
    0
).toFixed(1);

document.body.innerHTML = total; // Prints 0.0
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

The || operator isn't a "check for null and supply default function". It's a logical OR operator. The elements of your array are still being parsed as floats (as witnessed in your code)...

```
parseFloat(value[8]) + parseFloat(value[9]) + parseFloat(value[10]) + parseFloat(value[11]))
```

...and hence giving you the NaN value back for the left side of the logical OR operation.

You're going to have to check your values for NULL throughout your array and return 0 if any of them are NULL. Otherwise, calculate based on the values and return that instead.

Comment: Wrong, but nice try. Javascript is such a madness with it. Try window.console.log(NaN || 0); you'll get... 0. Answer's still valid about the check; you should check against valid values instead of only use || .

Comment: I wasn't attempting to state that NaN || 0 == NaN. I was stating that as a result of that line, he's still going to get NaN from the first part of it as he's still parsing his values as floats. Hence, THAT part still results in NaN, as there's no explicit null check. Editing now for clarity. The answer is still entirely correct.

Comment: "The elements of your array are still being parsed as floats" doesn't make much sense, and "giving you the NaN value back for the left side of the logical OR operation" is still the wrong conclusion.

Comment: The left side of the OR returns `"NaN"` not `NaN`, that's why the operator *fails*.

Comment: No, because you're still assuming that I'm stating the result of the entire operation. I'm not and never was attempting to state that. He even stated in the question that it's still coming back as NaN. I was merely restating that. Parse a null as a float and it returns NaN. It's as simple as that. And THAT's his major problem here.